# Line numbering such that each page first line number as 1

Tags: numbering

I want to number the lines in each page from starting from 1. By using the commands I have mentioned below I am not getting the desired numbering.

```
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
```

**Question :** Line number where numbering starts with 1 in each page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use

```
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
\linenumbers
```

Comment: Thanks @Marijn for editing my post